# How to set classes in angular-notify?

Tags: angularjs

```
notify({
     classes: 'alert-danger',
     message: response.data.errors[e]
});
```

I use this https://github.com/cgross/angular-notify

My notify still show blue color.

How to implement this classes?

Comment: I too have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem and was able to resolve it by changing the order of the css files in the main index.html file of my angularjs app. Apparently you have to list the angular-notify.css before the bootstrap.css file. This resolved the issue for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-notify/dist/angular-notify.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
```

Once I switched the order of the CSS styles, the bootstrap classes apply properly using your code above.